# May ma'aser funds be used for kimcha d'pischa?

Tags: halacha, passover, tzedakah-charity, maaser-tithes

May one use ma'aser money for kimcha d'pischa?

Comment: Are you assuming kimcha d'pischa is obligatory? If not, then I don't understand what the problem could be.

Comment: Thank you for your response, Double AA. I appreciate it. You make an excellent point. No, kimcha d'pischa is not obligatory. I was only seeking feedback on what people who DO give kimcha d'pischa do: Do they use maaser funds? Do individuals who give kimcha d'pischa "double dip", if you will, get "credit" for the pre-Pesach tzedaka in their overall maaser? I'm just curious what the general practice is. But your point is well taken. Because it is indeed not obligatory, each individual can do as he/she wishes. There are no rules, as such. Thanks again. Shabbat Shalom. Pesach Kasher v'Sameach.

Answer (score 5):

Although the Mishnas Yaavetz (simian 7) explains that the chiyuv of kimcha dpischa is more than just tzedaka, making it an obligation even if one has to borrow money to give it, RSZ says that nowadays is no longer like that. In Halichos Shlomo (Pesach, perek 2, dvar Halacha 3) he says that since today there’s no set collection or a set amount, it is allowed to be paid from Maaser.

R’ Nissim Karelitz agrees as well, in Chut Hashani (Pesach, 1:2)

Comment: Thank you very much, Chatzkel. Most enlightening and helpful. I greatly appreciate your assistance. Shabbat Shalom. Pesach Kasher v'Sameach.